# json_contains within an array returns empty set

Tags: mysql, json

I have a json array like

```
{  
   "response":[  
      {  
         "Rate Lock":"Yes",
         "Loan Amount":"1M - 2M",
         "Credit Score":"800",
         "Pre-Approved":"Yes",
         "Mortgage Type":"15 ARM",
         "Property Type":"Commercial",
         "Forecasted Close Date":"2018-07-12"
      }
   ]
}
```

in a column called 'custom_response'

```
select * from custom_deals_response where json_contains(`custom_response`,'"2018-07-12"')
```

returns and empty set. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

JSON_CONTAINS has 3 parameters(targer column, candidate, path(optional)). In you data structure your targer search column location inside `response` objects. You have to set 3 params to specific path where mySql have to search. [Documentation reference](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html)

> JSON_CONTAINS(target, candidate[, path])

```
 select * from custom_deals_response 
    where json_contains(`custom_response`,'{"Forecasted Close Date":"2018-07-12"}','$.response');
```

Comment: It would be nice if you'd surround your code by some explanation.

Comment: @zx485 Thank for comment. I've added description to answer.